# Error message for Snowflake SQL executed through R

Tags: sql, r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to execute a SQL query to the Lightcast Worker Profiles data through my R connection to Snowflake. Specifically, I'm using the DBI package to execute this query. This is my code:

```r
df <- dbGetQuery(conn, 
                     "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM US_PROFILES_ANONYMIZED.profiles")
```

When I log into Snowflake on my browser and click "Monitoring > Query History", I can see that the query was successful and am able to view the output. However, in R, I'm unable to actually get "df" added to my environment. Instead, I get the following error message:

> ! Error executing SQL:
> net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: JDBC driver internal error: exception creating result java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.arrow.memory.util.MemoryUtil at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.arrow.memory.ArrowBuf.getDirectBuffer(ArrowBuf.java:231).

Does anyone know an easy fix for this?